# no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: tensorflow

I training maskrcnn ,use tf-1.2 can train, but I use tf-1.5 it not training

The error is as follows：

```
Caused by op u'pyramid_1/AssignGTBoxes/Where_6', defined at:
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/letrain.py", line 349, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/letrain.py", line 346, in main
    LeTrain().model_train(user_mode)
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/platform/base_train.py", line 1228, in model_train
    cluster=self.cluster_spec)
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/platform/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 226, in create_clones
    outputs, feed_ops,verify_model_loss = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/platform/base_train.py", line 1195, in clone_fn
    model_loss, end_points, feed_ops = network_fn(data_direct, data_batch, int_network_fn)
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/letrain.py", line 214, in get_loss
    FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/fmrcnn/get_fmrcnn_loss.py", line 23, in model_fn
    loss_weights=[0.2, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0])
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/fmrcnn/libs/nets/pyramid_network.py", line 580, in build
    is_training=is_training, gt_boxes=gt_boxes)
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/fmrcnn/libs/nets/pyramid_network.py", line 263, in build_heads
    assign_boxes(rois, [rois, batch_inds], [2, 3, 4, 5])
  File "/home/zhouzd2/letrain/applications/fmrcnn/libs/layers/wrapper.py", line 173, in assign_boxes
    inds = tf.where(tf.equal(assigned_layers, l))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2538, in where
    return gen_array_ops.where(condition=condition, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6087, in where
    "Where", input=condition, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): WhereOp: Could not launch cub::DeviceReduce::Sum to count number of true / nonzero indices.  temp_storage_bytes: 1, status: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
     [[Node: pyramid_1/AssignGTBoxes/Where_6 = Where[T=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](pyramid_1/AssignGTBoxes/Equal_6_S9493)]]
     [[Node: pyramid_1/AssignGTBoxes/Reshape_8_G1028 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=5407481677180697062, tensor_name="edge_1349_pyramid_1/AssignGTBoxes/Reshape_8", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

No problem when loading calculation graphs, error is reported in sess.run()。
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or does anyone know what function can replace tf.where?
Thank you！

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Visual Studio**:

**Right click on the project > Properies > Cuda C/C++ > Device**

and add the following to **Code Generation** field

```
compute_30,sm_30;compute_35,sm_35;compute_37,sm_37;compute_50,sm_50;compute_52,sm_52;compute_60,sm_60;compute_61,sm_61;compute_70,sm_70;compute_75,sm_75;
```

Comment: This works for me however before adding the compute and sm values one must go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus and then actually check what compute values are supported by their GPU and add relevant values.